# Resolving t.co urls via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, short-url

I'm retrieving tweets via the Twitter anywhere API. I would like to treat pure text tweets and tweets that contain a picture differently.
I can do that by filtering for `pic.twitter.com` urls. Unfortunately the API delivers short urls ala `t.co`.

Is there a way to resolve these via Javascript (jQuery)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to resolve t.co URLs with AJAX because of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Basically, you are only allow to make requests to the server that hosts your page.

However, Twitter has a very rich API and contains very detailed metadata about elements in each tweet. You should read the [tweet entities](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities) documentation. These fields appear in the JSON documents of the [REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api).